# Skype new install not working on updated 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, skype

I was having problems answering a call in Skype, no answer button, and so I decided to reinstall Skype from scratch.

This is Xubuntu with lsb-release showing
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"

Ran this morning
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skypeforlinux

Get Skype from https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/

Downloaded skypeforlinux-64.deb

sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb

Started Skype from the menu.

Obtained the Skype window outline but no body, just what was showing under where the body should be. It just hangs there and I have to kill the pid to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This will remove the install currently there.

`sudo apt-get remove skypeforlinux-64.deb`

Then try downloading a fresh version and then running

`sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`

Then run the following

`sudo apt-get -f install skypeforlinux-64.deb`

The -f flag should pick up any needed dependencies that might be missing.

Let us know if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the filename used to install Skype, the package name is probably skypeforlinux.  Check that with:

```
dpkg -l |grep skype
```

The command to completely remove a package and all it's configuration files (which are probably what's causing your problmes),is:

```
sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux
```

(or `sudo apt-get remove --purge skypeforlinux`), NOT ...autoremove --purge.
(Use the skype package name you found if it's not skypeforlinux)

Now check that your home directory .Skype directory has been removed:

```
ls -a .Skype
```

No directory/file should be found, if it is, just remove it:

```
rm ~/.Skype
```

Then reinstall the downloaded skype deb file:

`sudo dkpg -i  skypeforlinux-64.deb`

This should result in a clean skype install.

Comment: didn't work!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did the following:

dpkg -l |grep skype

obtains skypeforlinux

apt-get remove --purge skypeforlinux

rm ~/.Skype Moved the directory to a backup directory.

Deleted the existing skypeforlinux-64.deb file and downloaded a new copy from the Skype page noted above.

dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb

Unpacking skypeforlinux (8.18.0.6)

Obtained the same result as previously where I just get the Skype frame outline and it hangs.

Found an older version of skypeforlinux-64.deb on a backup computer.

Unpacking skypeforlinux (5.4.0.1)

Obtained a Skype window with

Sorry, this version of Skype is not supported anymore.

The Sorry page had link to install Skype using snap.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/skype-is-now-available-as-snap/732fb227-3e0a-46b3-8cbc-55dd2fae09ab

snap install --classic skype

Skype is running now. Hopefully I will be able to answer calls that was the problem I was trying to correct when reinstalling Skype. I will let you know.

Comment: Says
Skype version 8.18.0.6
Calling version 2018.11.01.10